# Bootstrap 3 carousel error in IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using the new version of Bootstrap and jQuery

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

However I am getting the following error in IE8

```
Message: 'a.support.transition.end' is null or not an object
Line: 7
Char: 3824
Code: 0
URI: http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js
```

I found the following https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/7295.. however is I'm wondering why this problem isn't being experienced by more people. Why does bootstrap seem broken in IE8?

Comment: Seems they're missing a check for `$.support.transition` on [line 81](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.0.3/js/carousel.js#L81). Looks like it's fixed in [*master*](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/carousel.js#L71) though

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the devs have forgotten to check `$.support.transition` in the 3.0.3 release which is only set in browsers that support CSS transitions. They have instead, gone directly to `$.support.transition.end` which will not work in IE8 as `$.support.transition` is null.

Until the *master* branch is tagged as a new release, you could try patching it with this...

```
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
+function($) {
    'use strict';

    $.fn.carousel.Constructor.prototype.pause = function(e) {
        e || (this.paused = true)

        if (this.$element.find('.next, .prev').length && $.support.transition) {
            this.$element.trigger($.support.transition.end)
            this.cycle(true)
        }

        this.interval = clearInterval(this.interval)

        return this
    }
}(jQuery);
</script>
```

This is lifted directly from the [master branch](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/carousel.js#L71) and as you can see, it checks `$.support.transition` first.

FYI, it was fixed in master only a week ago ;) - https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/commit/ad64b0acc826a1ad1b1adc719960ac3020cc3539

Comment: Could you explain why there is an error and why this should fix it? Of course when you have time :) Appreciate your contributions